# HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request When using special character in asp.net 3.5 routing

Tags: webforms, .net-3.5

I have an .net framework 3.5 website in which I routed a path.

*site.com/mypath/text* goes to *site.com/webpage/* and the webpage gets the text.

This occurs when the text contains asterisk(*) or colon(:)

It's not an encoding problem * or %2A yelds the same result.
Most fixes for this problem are for framework 4 and above and I cannot upgrade.

The code I use:

```
  private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        CustomRouteHandler x = new CustomRouteHandler("~/page.aspx");

        routes.Add("mypath",new Route("mypath/{text}", x));
    }
```

Comment: How is the text getting into the URL? Could you do a replace on the asterisk with some other safe character at the source of the link and sidestep it that way?

Comment: @erastl: Can't do that. Some one else is calling the API.